# Uncaught Error: Class 'PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection' not found

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I have installed RabbitMQ, Composer and its dependencies like vendor folder and phpamqplib successfully.

But, still it is giving me an error that AMQPStreamConnection not found.
Can anyone help me?
Here, is my code-

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;
$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 15672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();
$channel->queue_declare('task_queue', false, true, false, false);
$data = implode(' ', array_slice($argv, 1));
if (empty($data)) {
    $data = "Hello World!";
}
$msg = new AMQPMessage(
    $data,
    array('delivery_mode' => AMQPMessage::DELIVERY_MODE_PERSISTENT)
);
$channel->basic_publish($msg, '', 'task_queue');
echo ' [x] Sent ', $data, "\n";
$channel->close();
$connection->close();
?>
```

Comment: Did you run `composer install` to download Amqp library?

Comment: Could you please show your composer.json?

Comment: Yes, I run composer install command to download the same library.

Comment: {
    "require": {
        "php-amqplib/php-amqplib": "^2.7"
    }
}
//This is my composer.json file

Comment: me too getting same problem

Answer (score 2):

Most probbably this is because **php-amqplib** could not be installed properly.

I had issues with **composer install** that I did not know because of which **php-amqplib** could not be installed.

**composer.json**

"php-amqplib/php-amqplib": ">=2.9.0"

**Issues with composer install:**

[image: Issues with composer install]

Then I ran **composer update** but that gave issues as well because of some libraries in **composer.json**

Then I finally I had to run following command to see successful installation of **php-amqplib** which resolved the issue. This command could be different for you as there could be different issues with installation on your system. Just keep an eye on composer command outputs.

**Command:**

composer update --no-plugins --no-scripts magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer

**Output:**

[image]

**PHP File:**

```
<?php
require_once('../../app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();
$channel->queue_declare('rabbitmq-dev', false, false, false, false);

$msg = new AMQPMessage('Hello World!');
$channel->basic_publish($msg, '', 'hello');

echo " [x] Sent 'Hello World!'\n";

$channel->close();
$connection->close(); ?>
```